# Finding a standard basis vector which when added to a set makes is a basis.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a standard basis vector for $\mathbb{R^3}$ that can be added to $ \{(1,1,1),(2,1,-3)\} $ to make a basis for $\mathbb{R^3}$.

My attempt would be to include an arbitrary vector in the set and say that we require the homogeneous system with associated matrix

$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & a \\
1 & 1 & b \\
1 & -3 & c \end{array} \right)$

to have the trivial solution only, and non-homogeneous system with the same associated matrix to have a unique solution.

We can "kill two birds" with just showing that the above matrix is non singular.

upon row reduction, I get.
$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & -a+2b \\
0 & 1 & a-b \\
0 & 0 & c+5b-6a \end{array} \right)$

The only choice left is the vector (0,0,1).

This way seems really long and rubbish, is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is quite systematic, there's nothing wrong with it :)

Of course, you have to watch out for common mistakes: $(0,0,1)$ is not "the only" choice you have. The only condition you have to ensure is that $$c+5b-6a\neq 0,$$ which gives us a multitude of choices - actually, your solution is really nice, because it gives us *all* the possible choices.

However, if you want just one particular vector, there are other, quicker ways.
For example, the two given vectors, $(1,1,1)$ and $(2,1,-3)$, span a two-dimensional plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
If we take something perpendicular to that plane, it will obviously be linearly independent.
The default way to get something perpendicular is to compute the cross product (also called vector product) of the two given vectors. So, you can just compute one cross product (which reduces to computing a $3\times 3$ determinant), and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to compute the determinant of a $3\times 3$ matrix, then it's enough to compute the determinant of your first matrix and you'll obtain a polynomial in $a,b,c$. Then, after you found some values for $a,b,c$ such that this polynomial is not zero, you obtain the vector your are looking for, i.e. the vector made by the three value you found

This is a general recipe, an advice could be to try set $a=b=0$, and compute the determinant in this easy case. You'll obtain a polynomial in $c$, which should be more easy to check if there exists a $c\in \mathbb{R}$ such that it's not the trivial polynomial. Then take the vector $(0,0,c)$ with the value of $c$ you found